# Написать: кому или куда?

Tags: грамотная-речь, управление

Как правильно: написать *в приёмную комиссию* или *приёмной комиссии*?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: **написать (куда?) в приемную комиссию.**

Управление для глагола ***написать***:

НАПИСАТЬ: где (в чём, на чём) / куда (во что).

Этот глагол требует обязательного дополнения: что? куда? во что?

Он написал письмо (кому?) брату. Он написал заявление (куда?) в приемную комиссию.

**Беспредложный дательный падеж** используется только  для **одушевленных**  существительных.